# p:inputSwitch doesn't show

Tags: jsf, netbeans, primefaces, jsf-2

I'm coding a xhtml webpage on JSF with Primefaces components under Netbeans IDE. I had an annoying issue with the p:inputSwitch tag, when I deploy my web application neither of my inputSwitch components are showing as should be.

Primefaces inputSwitch sample: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/inputSwitch.xhtml

[My four inputSwitch components](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHWm4.jpg)

index.xhtml

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <f:view contentType="text/html">
        <h:head>
            <f:facet name="first">
                <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
                <title>Parcial 2: Controlar arduino desde bluetooth con JSF+PrimeFaces</title>
            </f:facet>
            <script>
                function mostrarFormLeds() {
                    $("#formMinis").hide();
                    $("#formServos").hide();
                    $("#formLeds").show();
                }
                function mostrarFormMinis() {
                    $("#formLeds").hide();
                    $("#formServos").hide();
                    $("#formMinis").show();
                }
                function mostrarFormServos() {
                    $("#formMinis").hide();
                    $("#formLeds").hide();
                    $("#formServos").show();
                }
            </script>
        </h:head>
        <h:body>

            <p:layout fullPage="true">

                <p:layoutUnit position="north" size="100" resizable="true" closable="true" collapsible="true">
                    <h1 align="center">CENTRO DE CONTROL DE ARDUINO</h1>
                </p:layoutUnit>

                <p:layoutUnit position="south" size="100" closable="true" collapsible="true">
                    Footer
                </p:layoutUnit>

                <p:layoutUnit position="west" size="175" header="Menú de opciones" collapsible="true">
                    <h:form id="menuForm">
                        <p:menu>
                            <p:submenu label="Dispositivos">
                                <p:menuitem onclick="mostrarFormLeds()" value="LEDs" icon="ui-icon-lightbulb" ajax="true" />
                                <p:menuitem onclick="mostrarFormMinis()" value="Mini bombas" icon="ui-icon-pin-s" ajax="true"/>
                                <p:menuitem onclick="mostrarFormServos()" value="Servomotor" icon="ui-icon-gear" ajax="true"/>
                                <p:menuitem value="Themes" url="#" />
                            </p:submenu>
                        </p:menu>
                    </h:form>
                </p:layoutUnit>
                <p:layoutUnit position="center" >
                    <h:form id="formLeds" style="display:none;">
                        <p:growl id="msj-leds" autoUpdate="true" showDetail="true"/>
                        <p:growl id="msj-minis" autoUpdate="true" showDetail="true"/>
                        <p:growl id="msj-servos" autoUpdate="true" showDetail="true"/>
                        <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="margin-bottom:10px" cellpadding="5">
                            <!--Input Switches--------------------->
                            <p:inputSwitch value="#{ledsBean.led1}">  
                                <p:ajax listener="#{ledsBean.mostrarMensaje}" update="msj-leds"/>
                            </p:inputSwitch>
                            
                            <p:inputSwitch value="#{ledsBean.led2}">
                                <p:ajax listener="#{ledsBean.mostrarMensaje}" update="msj-leds"/>
                            </p:inputSwitch>
                            
                            <p:inputSwitch value="#{ledsBean.led3}">
                                <p:ajax listener="#{ledsBean.mostrarMensaje}" update="msj-leds"/>
                            </p:inputSwitch>
                            
                            <p:inputSwitch value="#{ledsBean.led4}">
                                <p:ajax listener="#{ledsBean.mostrarMensaje}" update="msj-leds"/>
                            </p:inputSwitch>
                            <!--Input Switches end--------------------->
                        </h:panelGrid>
                    </h:form>
                    <h:form id="formMinis" style="display:none;">
                    </h:form>
                    <h:form id="formServos" style="display:none;">
                    </h:form>

                </p:layoutUnit>

            </p:layout>

        </h:body>

    </f:view>
</html>
```

NOTE: I had to remove Netbeans default Primefaces (v 5.0)  and add Primefaces 6.0 as Maven dependency because 5.0 version doesn't have the inputSwitch tag.

Comment: Did you 'Clean and Build' project  after you modified Maven?

Comment: Yes, I do. I have a question: Upgrading primefaces 5.0 JAR to 6.0 is enough to get full funcionality?

Comment: Please create an [mcve]... please

Comment: Usually just JAR is needed but as @Kukeltje suggested it is hard to tell without more info. You can try to clear browser cache. If that doesnt work, then Im out of ideas.